# How to get more than 10 events for Outlook calendar API?

Tags: php, outlook, odata, outlook-restapi

I've modified the [official PHP example](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php) to get more than 10 calendar events

Here is the original OData query:

```
    $getEventsParameters = array (
        // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
        "\$select" => "Subject,Start,End,Location,Attendees,Organizer",
        // Sort by Start, oldest first
        "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime",
        // Return at most 10 results
        "\$top" => "10"
    );
```

I changed into:

```
    $getEventsParameters = array (
        // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
        "\$select" => "Subject,Start,End,Location,Attendees,Organizer",
        // Sort by Start, oldest first
        "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime"
    );
```

But I'm still only getting 10 events returned.  Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 is the default page size. To get more, put the `$top` parameter back in and increase it. <s>The maximum is 50.</s>

Since April 2017, the maximum is 1000 [see Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/)